# Adding new data to this array

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have an array that has been filled with default data as shown below

```php
$arrivals = array(
    "source" => "arrivals",
    "data" => array(
        0 => array("flight"=>"000","scheduled"=>"0000","city"=>"Geneva","airline"=>"UAL","gate"=>"A00","status"=>"1","remarks"=>"BOARDING"),
        1 => array("flight"=>rand(1,2000),"scheduled"=>randomTime(),"city"=>"Baltimore","airline"=>randomAirline(),"gate"=>"A7","status"=>"0","remarks"=>"") 
    )
);
```

Now i want to create the same array with data from a table in a loop using the same identifiers such as  'city'  but with variable names .
The other part is that the first part of 'data' array is a number which of course in a loop I can use a counter.

The problem is that the Array is created with the static value of ""source" => "arrivals" for which there is only one value for the array and then the arrays of 'data'.

I would like an easy way to set up an array dynamically with a number of records but with the one header of ""source" => "arrivals" and multiple entries for "data'  i.e. one element per record I fetch from my table

Thank you

Comment: Might be useful to see the other array and an example of what end result you would like

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a `foreach` loop in php after you have retrieved your data.

```
// Get the data from your table source
$data = get_some_data();

$arrivals = [
  'source' => 'arrivals',
  'data' => []
];

foreach ($data as $city) {
  $arrivals['data'][] = [
    'flight' => $city['flight'],
    'scheduled'=> $city['scheduled'],
    'city' => $city['city'],
    // etc.
  ];
}
```

Alternatively, if you would like to assign the city name as the array key in arrivals, you can replace the first line inside the foreach loop with `$arrivals['data'][$city['city']]` (or whatever array item holds the city value).

Comment: Thank you for the example it works very well for my data now.  Your help has been very much appreciated

Comment: @LeslieJarrett Great! I'm glad I was able to help. Can you please mark the answer as accepted? Thanks!